# Setting Alphabets into a double array in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
 char c; 
    for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c)
    {
        for(int i =1; i < newGui->width; i++)
        {
        //for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c)
            newGui->gui[0][i].graphics = c; 
        }
    }
```

So apparently my code is not setting the Alphabets into the double array properly, I cant figure out wether its the loop thats wrong or the logic that I have used in here.

Every-time I run the program it keeps setting all the double arrays with the value of 'Z'.

Can someone point me into right direction, thank you.

```
| . || Z || Z || Z || Z || Z |
| 1 || 0 || . || . || . || . |
| 2 || . || . || 0 || . || . |
| 3 || . || . || . || . || . |
| 4 || . || . || . || 0 || . |
```

Comment: You're overwriting `newGui->gui[0][i].graphics` with `'A'`, `'B`', ..., `'Z'`.  `'Z'` is last, which is why you see them all having that value.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Why is it overwriting the last value aka 'Z' only, if i may ask

Comment: Put a `printf` statement after `newGui->gui[0][i].graphics = c;`.

Comment: @Obamaself I do not see a "double array".

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Basically, something that can be copied, compiled, and run which shows the problem you're talking about.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica dont worry someone already solved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the inner `for` set `newGui->gui` at indexes interdependently of the character it is like your replace the external `for` by `c = 'Z';`

You want something like that :

```
    for(int i = 1; (i < newGui->width) && (i <= 'Z' - 'A' + 1) ; i++)
    {
        newGui->gui[0][i].graphics = i + 'A' - 1; 
    }
```

Note that way supposes the code of A, B ... Z are consecutive, which is true in ASCII, to be sure to have the expected behavior in all cases do :

```
    for(int i = 1; (i < newGui->width) && (i <= 26) ; i++)
    {
        newGui->gui[0][i].graphics = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[i-1]; 
    }
```